# What should I do if I find a closed question but I do not think the motivation is right?

Tags: discussion

This is an example: [FTP gives me an error when uploading and deleting files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512431/ftp-gives-me-a-error-when-uploading-and-deleting-files) where probably the problem is related to permissions and the server is an Ubuntu server.

What is the best-practice in this case?

Comment: When you need to guess the issue, it's unclear. Once you can say "the issue is related to X and Y that you can fix just fooring the bar" then the question is clear.

Comment: You did exactly what you should have done, post here!

Comment: Sorry, @Braiam, could you explain the meaning of "fooring the bar"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar